# Comparing Hilbert spaces of coupled and uncoupled qubits

Tags: mathematics, hilbert-space

Imagine two situations. In one, there are two qubits that are next to each other, that is, they have non-zero coupling terms in their Hamiltonian, and thus suffer from cross-talk and energy can leak from one to the other. In the other situation, the same qubits are separated, unconnected.

**Question:** How would you describe the Hilbert spaces of these two situations? What mathematical properties would the space of the coupled qubits have that the separated qubits wouldn't have?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Composite system postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Description_of_the_state_of_a_system):

"The Hilbert space of a composite system is the Hilbert space tensor product of the state spaces associated with the component systems. For a non-relativistic system consisting of a finite number of distinguishable particles, the component systems are the individual particles."

So the Hilbert spaces are the same in either case $\mathbb{C^2}\otimes \mathbb{C^2}$. What is different is not the Hilbert space, but rather the trajectories of states in these spaces, as they will depend on the unitary dynamics being driven by either a coupled or uncoupled Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thanks. Can you say (or mathematically formulate) anything about those trajectories? That's what I'm actually focused on --- I know it's the same Hilbert space.

Comment: it's going to depend greatly on the form of the hamiltonian. But if all the qubit 1 terms in your hamiltonian commute with all your qubit 2 terms, so that $H=H_{q1}+H_{q2}$ where $[H_{q1},H_{q2}]=0$, then your unitary $U(t)=\exp(iHt/\hbar)$ will factor into two commuting unitaries $U(t)=U_1(t)U_2(t)=U_2(t)U_1(t)$ with $U_1(t)=\exp(iH_{q1}t/\hbar)$ and $U_2(t)=\exp(iH_{q2}t/\hbar)$. Otherwise its tricky...